# SQL server:How to list primary key constraint columns of synonym refering a different SQL server database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, constraints

I'm trying to fetch primary key columns of synonym for which I've access that refers to a different database table then the one I've acces to. I tried with jdbc's 
`connection.getMetaData();
metaData.getPrimaryKeys(dbname,schemaName , synonymName);` but it gave me emty result. I also tried executing following sql queries 
`SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'synonymName' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME LIKE 'PK%';`

`SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'PK'  AND  parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID (synonymName);`

but it didn't help either. So is there any way to fetch primary key constrains of synonym where table refered is in another db to which there is no straight forward excess.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below query. If your base table in a different database, then you may need to prefix the database name as well. This will be good to start with.

```
select c.*, ob.name
from
   sys.columns c
   inner join sys.synonyms s on c.object_id = object_id(s.base_object_name)
   INNER JOIN sys.objects ob ON c.object_id = ob.object_id
   INNER JOIN sys.indexes i ON i.object_id = c.Object_id 
   INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON  i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID
   AND i.object_id = ic.object_id AND
   i.index_id = ic.index_id and i.is_primary_key = 1
   AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
where
   s.name = 'synonymName'
```